# Mongodb:mogoose save not fired

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

Just started with mongodb and trying to achieve insert collection but i am struggled  with it.

**user_model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
   name:String,
   email:String,
   password:String,
   phone:Number,
   _enabled:Boolean
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var User   =  require('../models/user_model.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/test',function(err){
   console.log(err);
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var new_user = new User({
    name:'hjhj',
    email: 'jjjjhj',
    password: 'jhjhj',
    phone: '7778',
    _enabled:false 
});
new_user.save(function(err,User){
  console.log("insdie");
  if(err) return res.json(err);
  console.log("After insert",User); 
       });

    });

 });
```

There is no errors but `new_user.save(function(err){}` not fired however if there is a validation error occurs error callback is fired with proper error message.

Comment: Read the Documentation. [`createConnection()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-createConnection) does not take a callback. You generally should be using `connect()` with the `{ useMongoClient: true }` option, just like the WARNING message you likely saw actually would have told you to do. `.connect()` returns a callback or promise and immediately initiates a connection. `createConnection()` does not, an merely creates a "connection handle" that you have not actually done anything with. In truth it has a different intended purpose.

Comment: thanks its worked now:)

Comment: Is there anyway to globally get an object for this `var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test',{ useMongoClient: true }); otherise i will write this in every place where the model use
`

Comment: You don't need to connect in every model. Models "register" with mongoose, generally via `mongoose.model('Name',schema)`. So importing `mongoose` ( remember that node evals just once ) is not the same as "connecting". You connect "once".

Comment: little bit clarification is needed  `So importing mongoose ( remember that node evals just once ) is not the same as "connecting". You connect "once".`

Comment: Seems like you need to do some reading. This is explained elsewhere, and several times. There is also no shortage of sample code out there defining models in different files. A bit beyond the scope of a question here on Stack Overflow. There might be some "short" answers, but there are far more articles and documentation and code available. Read those  for "big picture". Ask here for "specifics".